# how to parse an array item android?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

How can I parse an Item in an Array? Here is an example of where this is needed:

```
String thing= Array1;
    final String[] SplitArray = thing.substring(1).split(" ");
```

This splits it on the space and makes the array `SplitArray` now how can i split each item in the array on the `;`? Say my array is `Array1 = Hello;Hellothere Hi;Hithere`

Comment: There is hardly any relation to Android here. This is a basic Java issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split(";| ")` in case you wanna split both ';' and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `.split(";")` does that. What are you really asking?

Comment: I am asking how to split the item after its in the array.